# Is there an API endpoint to get the kubeconfig file of a cluster from Rancher using its own API?

Tags: rancher, rancher-cli

I'm trying to find a way to get the kubeconfig file using `curl` command and hit the rancher API. Is there an API endpoint to get that ?

I tried calling these following endpoints but no luck.

```
https://clusters.bazzinga.com/v3/clusters/c-abcde?action=importYaml
https://clusters.bazzinga.com/v3/clusters/c-abcde?action=generateKubeconfig
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Rancher docs](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/api/#making-requests)

> Most resources have actions, which do something or change the state of the resource. To use these, send a HTTP POST to the URL in the actions map for the action you want ...

This works for me like a charm:

```sh
curl -s -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $RANCHER_TOKEN" https://clusters.bazzinga.com/v3/clusters/c-abcde?action=generateKubeconfig | jq -r ".config"
```

Comment: `action=generateKubeconfig`
Does it generate a new Kubeconfig ? My objective is not to create a new kubeconfig. I would like to get the existing kubeconfig. 
@Vlad

Comment: @Gautham I ran it like 5 times, and every time it produced the same config :) Token used in config is, so-called, Kubeconfig token owned by user whom makes request